# How to copy an object to the exact same position across a guide?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I want to create a steering wheel, similiar to this:

[image: steering wheel]

So I have started with the outer circle and given it a wide stroke, I am now on the middle bit. I have the following:

[image: distribute artwork trouble]

Can someone please tell me how I can move that bottom-right circle to be in the exact position on the left across the guide I have running through the center of the circle?

Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select the oval with the `Move` tool (<kbd>V</kbd>).
2. Choose the `Reflect` tool (<kbd>O</kbd>, might be hidden under the
   `Rotate` tool in the toolbox).
3. Press and hold <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> to have three dots show up with
   your reflect cursor.
4. While still holding, click your vertical axis/guide. Enabling `Smart
   Guides` (<kbd>Control/Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or `View > Smart
   Guides`) may help getting your click location exactly right.
5. In the dialog that pops up, choose `Vertical` for the axis and click
   `Copy` rather than `OK`.

Answer (score 2):

Lock everything except the oval you want to move.

Draw a box on the right-hand side which aligns to your three guides.

Group the box and the oval.

Flip a *copy* of it vertically (I think — I always screw up the axis) so that the left side of the square, the one along the center axis, stays on the center guide going through the center of the steering wheel.

Ungroup both boxes and ovals and delete the guide boxes.

**ETA pictures:** Although Bakabaka's answer is much better

[image: original]

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to clarify on the `Draw a box on the right-hand side` bit! I can't quite see or understand what you mean :(